# How to obfuscate SSH tunnel Mac?

Tags: encryption, ssh, obfuscation, tunneling

I am looking to test a DPI (deep packet inspector). I currently have it set up to block SSH connections (which it does successfully).

I have learned that DPI can be bypassed by obfuscating/encrypting the initial handshake (I think, feel free to correct).  By doing this, the DPI is not able to tell that the traffic is SSH and does not block it. **How can achieve this with macOS?**

I have complete control over both the server and the client.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be answered on [Apple Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86278/ssh-command-has-no-z-option-obfuscated-ssh-client). Note that the patch mentioned there seems to be no longer maintained, so it may have security issues if you do not backport fixes. A more up-to-date patch (supporting OpenSSH 7.6 as of this answer) is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/zinglau/obfuscated-openssh-patches).<sup>*</sup> This particular obfuscated protocol is explained in more detail [on its site](https://zinglau.com/projects/ObfuscatedOpenSSHPatches.html). Judging by a quick read of the patch, this particular obfuscation seems to add a random length of padding to packets and encrypt the handshake using a preshared key stored in the configuration file of both the client and server. It is not particularly advanced, but will likely hamper automated protocol detection.

There are other ways to obfuscate SSH traffic as well. You could create an obfuscated VPN tunnel between the client and server and connect with SSH through that. I explained in [another answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/187652/106285) how to prevent OpenVPN traffic from being detected as such. You could use the techniques outlined in it ([static keys](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/static-key-mini-howto/) and [obfsproxy](https://web.archive.org/web/20180412070310/http://dcamero.azurewebsites.net:80/openvpn-obfsproxy.html)) to create a tunnel through which SSH can run. You need only a basic understanding of networking to bring up a virtual interface for the tunnels and assign a local IP to it so you can connect using your SSH utility. You can also [use obfsproxy directly](https://blog.anthonywong.net/2015/09/26/obfuscated-ssh-tunnel/) on SSH.

It's important to remember that, while protocol obfuscation can make automated detection or censorship more difficult, it does little to prevent an intelligent analyst with access to traffic dumps from realizing that the traffic is OpenSSH traffic. There is not much you can do to protect against such a threat while maintaining usability. All obfuscation does is raise the bar for detection.

<sub>* Applying a patch requires you know how to compile software from source code. You download the source code for the exact version targeted by the patch, and use a command to [apply the patch](http://stephenjungels.com/jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html), such as the `patch` utility.</sub>

Comment: I had found that before, but for the reasons you pointed out it does not seem too secure. I am not familiar with back porting fixes. Could you assist with that?

Comment: @JBis I cannot, sorry. However, the other patch I linked to is much newer, supporting 7.6.

Comment: I am also not sure how to set it up on the server.

Comment: What operating system is the server running?

Comment: macOS (Server) :)

Comment: And how does the patch work. It says `.diff` so I am guessing that I just copy what's in the diff to the original? Do I have to do that for each version or just the latest?

Comment: Then it should be the same procedure as doing it on your client. It looks like you just pass `-Z` to the client, and the server will automatically support obfuscation (just a guess based on skimming the code). As for applying the patch, I will edit my answer to explain how to do that.

Comment: @JBis found here: https://zinglau.com/projects/ObfuscatedOpenSSHPatches.html

Comment: Ok. Thanks for help I will mark as accepted soon just want to test out (don't worry I won't forget :)

Comment: There is server side setup check the link.

Comment: It looks like all it needs is a quick change to the configuration file and the addition of a key and port. I  have added the link to my answer to make it more readable for anyone else who may have the same problem, good find!. :)

Comment: Having problem installing. Will try tomorrow.

Comment: Getting `configure: error: OpenSSL version header not found.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28638516/7886229 Fixed it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80074/discussion-between-jbis-and-forest).

Comment: @JBis Did this answer end up helping solve your problem?

Comment: Helped but didn't answer. Couldn't get patch to work.

Comment: That's too bad. I think StackOverflow will help more with applying the patch itself. Sorry I wasn't able to help more.

Comment: No problem. And thanks for your help :) Appreciate it! P.S. Sorry I didnt respond in chat. Didn't see reply until  today :(