# Is it possible to see someone using vpn who is connected to my AP and turned on hotspot for his mobile in which he uses vpn

Tags: wifi, vpn, monitoring, hotspot

I want to monitor traffic in my Access point of the users who turned on hotspots in their PC after connecting to the wi-fi.
I want to monitor users who use vpn to access blocked sites in my organization by connecting their mobile phones to their PC hotspot which has internet from my Access point.

Comment: What you can do at the access point depends on its capabilities regarding network analysis or your ability to capture data on the AP and analyze them. In theory it is possible. See [Is it possible to detect VPN in the network?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187649/is-it-possible-to-detect-vpn-in-the-network), [SSL VPN Detection and possible to block](/questions/42735/) ...